# Is there a situation where an unaligned data will cause an x86 CPU to produce an exception?

Tags: exception, assembly, x86

I have read that some CPUs will produce an exception if they tried to access an unaligned data.

Based on a testing I made, an x86 CPU did not produce an exception when trying to access an unaligned data, but I am wondering is there a situation where an unaligned data will cause an x86 CPU to produce an exception?

Comment: The SIMD (SSE+, AVX, AVX2 etc) aligned instructions will throw an exception. Depending on the x86 processor unaligned data may not throw an exception but may suffer performance penalties. An example of an aligned SIMD instruction is [_MOVAPS_](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVAPS.html) . The `A` in the instruction denotes an alignment requirement.

Answer (score 6):

On x86, if you set the AM flag in the CR0 register and set the AC flag in the EFLAGS register, then any unaligned memory access at CPL 3 (user priv level) will cause an #AC exception (interrupt 17).  Since normally these bits are clear, and access to them is privileged you'd need to go to some effort to enable them (which might be impossible on some OSes).

Comment: And if you do, library functions like memcpy may start faulting.  AFAIK, it's not practical to have AC enabled while running "normal" compiled code that uses normal standard libraries, because it will all have been compiled assuming that unaligned access is fine.  It's rare, but not rare enough to do much without hitting problems, I'm guessing.